# How to iterate over all combinations of keywords and subreddits using RedditExtractoR::find_thread_urls()

Tags: r, function, reddit

Firstly, sorry for the confusing title, I had no idea where to start with this!

I am looking at passing a string of characters into the `find_thread_urls()` function from `RedditExtractoR`. I want to save iterating through each of the 6 possible iterations in the below example code (which does not work).

Is there a neat way of doing this?

```
library(RedditExtractoR)

keywords <- c('cats', 'dogs', 'catnip')
subreddit <- c('cats', 'animals')
post_urls <- find_thread_urls(keywords = keywords,
                              subreddit = subreddit)
```

Comment: tl;dr: `post_urls <- outer(keywords, subreddits, find_thread_urls)`

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with RedditExtractoR, but a generic solution to this kind of task is to use nested `lapply()` calls:

```
library(RedditExtractoR)

post_urls <- lapply(
  setNames(keywords, keywords),
  \(kw) lapply(
    setNames(subreddit, subreddit),
    \(sr) paste(kw, sr)
  )
)
```

(The `setNames()` calls makes it so the output list is named based on the inputs.)